# Augmented Dickey-Full Test Standard Error

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am currently reading *Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting (Brockwell & Davis 2016)* and am struggling to understand the following (pg 170 for those with the book).

The unit root test for an AR(1) process takes the following form:

$$\nabla X_t = \phi_0^*+\phi_1^*X_{t-1}+Z_t\\
\phi_0^* = \mu(1-\phi_1)\\
\phi_1^* =\phi_1-1$$

Since we are testing for the unit root, $H_o$ is $\phi_1=1$ or $\phi_1^*=0$.

The text gives the following equation to calculate the test statistic in the AR(1) case:

$$\hat{\tau}_\mu=\frac{\phi_1^*}{\sqrt{\Big(\frac{\sum_{t=2}^n(\nabla X_t-\phi_0^*-\phi_1^*X_{t-1})^2}{n-3}\Big)/(\sum_{t=2}^n(X_{t-1}-\bar{X})^2)}}$$

I wish to test the unit root for an AR(2) process which can be rewritten as:

$$\nabla X_t = \phi_0^*+\phi_1^*X_{t-1}+ \phi_2^*\nabla X_{t-1}+ Z_t$$

My question is: should I just treat this as one would with a standard multiple linear regression problem where your estimate for the new standard error of $
\phi_1^*$ is $\sqrt{\frac{SSE}{n-p-1}} a^*$ where $a^*$ is the diagonal entry in the matrix $(X^TX)^{-1}$ corresponding to $\phi_1^*$? Or is there another way of doing this for the Dickey Fuller test?